# Is it more expensive an authentication system based on HMAC over HTTP or single-token over HTTPS?

Tags: web-services, security, http, cryptography, hmac

The 1st case would require to generate for each communication a HMAC identifying the request, so the server can re-generate it to make sure the client is authorized (because the HMAC is encryped with a private key that is only known by the server and the client), while the 2nd one only requires the service to issue the certificate (or token) once, and keep it live for some minutes -ex. 15 minutes-. Of course to prevent MITM or Replay attacks it must be sent only over SSL, with all the conseguences (more bandwitdh and more CPU requirements).

Personally I find the 1st to be not only simpler but also stronger, because each request has its own unique data, while the 2nd relies on the SSL certificate integrity (I'm not saying that's easy to crack a signed SSL certificate, but if someone would break it all the traffic would be sniffed for all communications).

So I find them to have the following pro/cons:

- HMAC pros: unique token for each request, can be really secure against MITM and Replay attacks -by using unique data to compose the signature and a timestamp-, easy to implement
- HMAC cons: requires the server to work for each single request to re-generate the token
- Token pro: one token for multiple requests, useful on services that require multiple client actions
- Token cons: requires SSL for all communications.

I think I'd need to set up some tests to get a final answer, but I'd love to hear if someone has already some knowledge or some tought based on old experiences.

Comment: What so you mean by "expensive"? To build? To maintain? In CPU resources?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I should be more clear: I mean which is more expensive by resource usage (in order to handle the incoming connection). Which one generates takes more resources to be executed.

Comment: In that case, it will be easy (as Pavel mentions): asymmetric encryption is always more expensive than symmetric, and encryption is more expensive than signing (as a general rule of thumb; I'm sure there is some less-secure asymmetric thing that is cheaper than a secure symmetric one, etc...). Now, seeing how modern servers can handle thousands of SSL connections a second (and hundreds of thousands HMAC signings), you have to be working on a pretty high-traffic site for this to matter. Probably SSL is way cheaper in devel-hours...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HMACs and PKIs are designed to solve very different problems.

If you are trying to protect the message from being modified in transit, then HMAC is designed to solve that problem, and will serve you well.

If you are trying to prevent the message from being read in transit, than your only option is a PKI (such as SSL). A PKI provides a strictly stronger guarantee than an HMAC though -- after all, if one can't read the message, it is awfully difficult to make meaningful modifications to that message :)

If you transmit the secret used by a HMAC over a PKI, note that it is impossible for the HMAC to be *more* secure than the PKI system. After all, if you break the PKI then you can just read the HMAC secret.

Most all of the bandwidth overheads of SSL are going to be in the handshaking process; if you're going to be sending anything over SSL there's little reason to not send the rest of your communications over SSL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only password-based (or key-based) authentication of clients over HTTP, HMAC is better solution. Modern HMACs are more reliable than public key algorithms in terms of cryptoanalysis.

Generating of random tokens on server side is less overhead than performing a public key transformations.

P.S. If problem can be solved in terms of symmetric cryptography, it's better to solve them in terms of symmetric cryptography.